Do lasers with optical isolator or synchrotron radiation sources allow for Rabi cycles?
In Rabi cycle two-level system cyclically transitions between ground and excited state - bringing question where their energy difference goes during these transitions?
For transition from ground to excited state, energy seems to come from photon source (photon absorption?), suggesting that for the opposite transition energy goes back to laser as EM radiation, photon? Is it related with stimulated emission like in STED microscope?
In this case, if using unidirectional lasers: e.g. with optical isolator or from synchronous radiation, such photons going back to laser seem forbidden - bringing question: is Rabi cycle observed with such unidirectional types of lasers?
Searching for "Rabi oscillation synchronous radiation", I have found this article: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04948-y , which first states that it has turned out much more difficult than expected:

although intense nanometre-wavelength light sources have been available for more than a decade [7,8,9], Rabi dynamics at such short wavelengths has not been directly observed.


despite theoretical predictions to observe Rabi dynamics at short wavelengths [18,19,20,21], its effects on the measured spectra were only indirect [22,23]

And it claims it has finally observed, however, showing these Fig. 3 plots:

in which personally I see approaching stationary probability distribution instead of cycles - does this article really observe Rabi cycles?
Are there different articles showing observation of Rabi cycles for such unidirectional lasers?
If indeed Rabi can be forbidden this way, one of applications might be better state preparation (as excited) for quantum computers.
Update: For damped Rabi oscillations, population should approach 1/2 - 1/2 (source of below slide), while in plots above it approaches nearly completely excited state.

Update: Instead of Rabi cycle, seems this synchrotron article has observed Autler–Townes effect (also called AC Stark effect) - first shock response of atoms to the wave, than stabilization in AC EM wave.

Can you elaborate on what you mean by unidirectional laser? Do you mean any typical laser, as most have built-in optical isolators? If so, Rabi oscillations are a common tool for state manipulation within atomic ultracold samples.

@Noct, as in the title or description: in which photons can travel only in one direction, for example due to optical isolator (blocking one direction by Faraday effect), or from synchrotron radiation (synchrotrons, wigglers, unddulators, free electron lasers).

So the short answer is: yes. Sources of coherent radiation like a laser with an optical isolator allow for driving Rabi oscillations. The energy is transferred between the system and the driving field, and the direction of propagation of that field in the simplest case does not matter. For a real-life example, you can check the Pi and Pi/2 pulses concept in atomic interferometers.

@Noct, for synchrotron radiation the above Nature article says previous attempts were unsuccessful and then show own "successful": without cycles (plots above). For optical isolator it is more subtle: they block in narrow spectrum, placement might be crucial - could you suggest some articles, settings?

To drive a Rabi flopping as discussed here you need a proper two-level system and a coherent field. In alkali atoms, which I am most familiar with, you can obtain those conditions by driving radio transition between the hyperfine ground levels like in this thesis (https://tzin.bgu.ac.il/atomchip/Theses/Anat_Daniel_MSc_2012.pdf ; page 58) or you bridge those two levels through a third level with a laser pair like here (http://ultracold.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/files/Masterarbeit_2021_Nilab.pdf ; page 46).  To comment on the paper you submitted I would need to properly read it.

Thank you, I see the first in page 38 has quite complicated setting - photons might go back, the second doesn't use topological isolator. The closest to this nonobservation for synchrotron would be Rabi cycle using ring laser with topological isolator. Generally in Rabi cycle, 2-state system energy increases and decreases: requiring photons traveling there and back - how could it happen if forbidding one of them? I think photons should travel only there in such case - leading to stabilization instead of cycle, as we see in plots from experiment above.

The optical isolator does not affect the laser. It keeps back reflections from re-entering the laser. This is not to say that the light in the laser medium is all moving unidirectionally, or that this even matters for the Towne's doublet reported in that paper. If I understand correctly, these guys in the publication demonstrate that their laser was coherent enough to be the perturbation field in an AC Stark effect on Helium atoms.
In my experience with typical lasers, optical isolators are only used to avoid back reflections, which are terrible for the laser's stability. The cavity of the laser always dictates its beam direction. FELs and synchrotrons are slightly different, but I think the principle is still the same.
A system undergoing Rabi oscillations (or cycles, the same thing) is simply a two-state system that has been subjected to a coherent AC electric field tuned to the frequency of one of the two states. The system will oscillate between the two states at the Rabi frequency. The Hamiltonian of interest is that of the He atoms (not the laser), of which the AC electric field (which could come from any laser) is a perturbation. The source of the AC field could literally be anything so long as it is coherent and at the proper frequency.
At no point are the He atoms returning a photon to the laser.
Now, if the laser is not coherent, you will have trouble observing Rabi oscillations. So, in the paper, they say something like: We want to show that a FEL can be coherent enough to do this thing all other lasers can do. You can drive Rabi oscillations in the visible and IR using a cheap laser pointer, with or without an optical isolator; it doesn't matter. People have been doing it for almost a century, but not with FELs. These guys did it at the extreme UV using an FEL, which is technologically impressive because FELs are still in an infantile stage of development (compared to gas or diode lasers). They predicted that their laser was coherent enough, and it was. Nothing is being discovered.

So why they cannot observe Rabi for synchrotron radiation - the only article claiming observation does not have cycles? (plots above) Similar is ring laser with optical isolator - was there observed Rabi cycle for it?

I think this is more about these light sources' practical coherence length/time, which determines if they can be used as a driving field for the rabi oscillations of a totally different system. The laser has no idea what it's getting used for, and in this case, it's shining onto He atoms and causing the He atoms to have rabi oscillations. The He atoms don't know anything about the laser operating principle either. And for such short wavelengths, it doesn't seem surprising that coherence time/length is a practical challenge in these experiments.

As you can see in quotes at the top for synchrotron, multiple times they predicted but did not observe, the best observation says "cycles", but shows plots from experiment with stabilization instead. In Rabi laser periodically increases and decreases energy of target - the former is by photon traveling to the target, so isn't the latter by photon traveling back? In synchrotron electrons produce photons, but cannot absorb them back - if you don't like this explanation, please provide another for nonobservation in various attempts against standard Rabi theory (why not missing some assumption?)

I added to my answer to address this comment.

I have added damped Rabi oscillations slide above - population should approach 1/2-1/2 in Rabi, what is definitely not true for these synchrotron experimental results.

I can't figure out what this question is about anymore.

The main question of focus here was supposed to be the synchrotron paper - first emphasizing that many others against theory did not observe Rabi in the past, then showing results which are very far from Rabi, do not approach 1/2-1/2 population as required. Can you defend it has observed Rabi? If not, maybe there is missing assumption in Rabi theory - e.g. it needs energy exchange in both directions, but some photon sources does not allow for that.

@JarekDuda As I mentioned in my response. No one claims that the direct Rabi cycles were observed. They've seen Autler Towns doublet. Please refer to the theses that I already provided plus this script https://atomoptics.uoregon.edu/~dsteck/teaching/quantum-optics/ to better understand the processes you talk about.

I completely agree they observed Autler–Townes effect, which is dynamical version of Stark effect: kind of shock of the atoms due to incoming wave, then stabilization in its AC field. But this is different than Rabi effect e.g. leading to 1/2-1/2 population. So we agree there is no Rabi here - what I suspect is universal for synchrotron sources allowing only one photon direction (while Rabi requires exchange in both directions). So maybe Rabi could be also forbidden for different sources, like ring laser with optical isolator?

Again, it seems you are missing the point: "What I suspect is universal for synchrotron sources allowing only one photon direction (while Rabi requires exchange in both directions)." <---- THIS sentence is nonsense in more than one way. Also, that paper is not about a synchrotron but an FEL. Further, Rabi Oscillations, Autler-Townes Doublet, and AC Stark all refer to the same physics. You construct an AC Stark effect experiment and then observe the A-T doublet, which is two states separated by the Rabi frequency. These things are not "this effect" or "that effect."

Rabi is periodically causing excitation and deexcitation by laser, the same looking in CPT perspective - so this is exchange of photons between resonator/active medium and external atoms (FEL using synchrotron don't have). In hydrodynamical analog, we can imagine standing water wave in rectangular tank, and rest particle outside should also oscillate exchanging momentum with this resonantor. Autler-Townes is completely different - they see only initial shock, then stabilization to AC Stark - no Rabi oscillations, what should be universal for synchrotron sources.

I believe that OP's question stems from a misconception that when Rabi flopping is driven, the energy is transferred between the two-level system and the source of the radiation. This is not true because the energy is transferred between the system and the driving field. As pointed out by ABetheGammow in their answer, it does not matter what the source of the field is, as it is not part of the process. So to answer:

[...] where does their energy difference go during these transitions?

The energy stays within the field/two-level system pair.
About the second question, which I believe that I already answered in the comments under the main post:

is the Rabi cycle observed with such unidirectional types of lasers?

Yes, it is a common tool. You can use "unidirectional" laser or even an antena and here are two examples:

https://tzin.bgu.ac.il/atomchip/Theses/Anat_Daniel_MSc_2012.pdf
http://ultracold.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/files/Masterarbeit_2021_Nilab.pdf

And finally, regarding the article: no one claims there that the Rabi cycles were observed directly. Even in the title, it says: Rabi dynamics. The authors observed the Autler-Townes doublet, which is an emergent feature of the aforementioned dynamics.
